# Remove all Zero at end in string using Regex

Tags: .net, regex, string

I have to Remove Zero at the end of string only if string have `,` in it. Can i do all below using Regex. 
So

```
123,90 -> 123,9
123,00 -> 123,
123,0 -> 123,
123,0090 ->123,009
00,34-> 00,34
ABC -> ABC
```

Comment: Perhaps, `s.Contains(",") ? s.TrimEnd('0') : s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search using this regex:

```
(,\d*?)0+\b
```

and replace it by:

```
$1
```

[IdeOne Code demo](http://ideone.com/8Pkuw7)

[RegExStrorm Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%2C%5Cd*%3F)0%2B%5Cb&i=123%2C90%0D%0A123%2C00%0D%0A123%2C0%0D%0A123%2C0090%0D%0A00%2C34%0D%0AABC&r=%241) - Click on `"Context"` tab to see results

[RegEx101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vH2cG4/2)

Comment: Hey anu. Tis works perfect. But how to adjust this expression to remove from start also. 00123,2500 -> 123,25

Comment: [In that case search using `\b0*(\d*,\d*?)0+\b` regex](https://regex101.com/r/vH2cG4/3)

Comment: Hey but it break when 0001869,0258 . Should be 1869,0258 but coming as 0001869,0258

Comment: What will happen to `00,34` in your question?

Comment: It should come up as ,34. but should not change anything if no comma . This works as of now

Comment: But your questions says `00,34-> 00,34`.  Has that requirement changed now?

Comment: [You can try this regex `(,\d*?)0+\b|(?<!,)\b0+`](https://regex101.com/r/vH2cG4/4)

Comment: Ya I missed that. I need to remove all trailing and leading zeros only when , exist. The updated expression failed with 00ABC00. Its should not change anything but it giving ABC00

Answer (score 1):

Remember than **RegEx** is used to **test** a pattern. It will return true or false rather than perform any changes to the string itself.

If you want to search for characters at the end of a string, you can use the $ sign to build your regex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl42N.png)

Use [this tool](https://regex101.com/) if you want to test this live

So, this RegEx will return **true** each time you have a 0 at the end, **false** otherwise

```
0$
```

Now, if you need to **remove** that zero, you need to perform a TRIM

```
"129,0".TrimEnd('0')
```

Note the quotes within the TrimEnd function. This is because this method expects a char an not a string.

Regards!
Rod

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you use `,` as number-decimal-separator. So you could use [`double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`double.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the desired result:

```
string str = "123,0090";
double d;
if (double.TryParse(str, out d))
    str = d.ToString();
```

If you want to ensure that comma is used as decimal separator:

```
if (double.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("de-DE"), out d))
    str = d.ToString();
```

If you'd use `decimal.TryParse` instead the number of trailing zeros would be preserved which isn't desired in this case. [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx): *"The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. ....might be revealed by the `ToString` method...."*

Answer (score 0):

```
     String line = "120,90";


    String newLine = line.replaceAll("0*$", "");
//120,9
```

removes any '0' starting from the end of the string expression. Replaces all 0s with empty space from the end of the string up to the first non 0 character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in Javascript you can do as follow :

```
'0.000015000000'.replaceAll(/0*$/g, "")
```

Return "0.000015"

Comment: That's not a JS question, it's marked as .net